# Horizontally aligned divs within wrapper, with dynamic width, one being centered

Tags: css

[image]

I need both divs to have dynamic width.
The gray one has to be centered, while the blue one to float right BUT both be horizontally alingned.

These to are sitting in a wrapper.

The problem is that in order to have varying width I use `display:block` and this makes the gray div to push the other one down.

How can I manage this without setting a fixed width for the gray div?

EDIT

This is how it should look like. I just put another left floating div.
[image]

The red div has to be perfectly centered.
All divs' width must be dynamic.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Isn't `float:left` an option?

Comment: Are the green and blue div's the same width? if not, if the red div is centered with respect to the parent block, then the gap between green-red will differ from red-blue.  However, you might mean keep the green-red gap the same as red-blue.  Please clarify.

Comment: There is content in both sides and other can be added. The width of those two side divs can differ, I guess the red one would stay centered with respect to the parent block, but I belive it would be nicer to keep equal distances from the side ones.

Comment: Now that Josh mentioned about absolute positioning, I made use of it like so http://jsfiddle.net/Yj6bd/

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the blue div within the grey one and absolutely position it, using `left:100%` will make it horizontally dock to the right side of the grey div.

Just one of many options.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HnsEx/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle :)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qLTMf/)

and css

```
#parent {
overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red
    }
    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #888;
    }
    .left {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ccc
    }
```